# Angular 6 Click Event on document.getElementsByClassName live html Collection

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a [innerHtml] that has several classes I want to add click events to:

```css
...

inner = server.getInnerHtml();

ngAfterViewInit(){
  var els = document.getElementsByClassName("highlight"); //I want all the html elements with class ".highlight"
  console.log(els.length); //its 0!!!
  Array.from(els).forEach( el =>{
    console.log(el)
  });
  console.log(els); //this prints fine, i guess since live collection
}
```

```html
<div [innerHtml]="inner | safeHtml"></div>
```

How do I add a click event listener to each element in the elements array once the live collection has loaded in Angular?  Is there a way to do with by making the collection a observable?

Thanks

Comment: Try `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Whoops, I mean to put ngAfterViewInit.  Doesn't work, i think because it takes time for the innerHtml to render, even after the view initializes.

Comment: I do not see any element with this class

Comment: @brk it is a element inside the innerHtml called "inner".

Comment: An alternative is to listen to click events on the document or on the window, and check if the `event.target` has the `highlight` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the stackblitz code that listens for click event for document.element that contains class name 'highlight'.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jgeapi

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work if I set a timeout for a second, but not right after the view initializes, since I am fetching data from my api. Is there anyway to check a specific div for changes then to run the code in your ngAfterVkewInit?

Comment: We can only catch asyncronous code using observable. Not possible to check whether DOM is changed or not. Please upvote it it is right